# How to fix NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, scikit-multilearn

I am running the [code] of multi-label classification[1](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/08/introduction-to-multi-label-classification/).how to fix the NameError that the "X_train" is not defined.the python code is given below.

```
import scipy
from scipy.io import arff
data, meta = scipy.io.arff.loadarff('./yeast/yeast-train.arff')
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification

# this will generate a random multi-label dataset
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(sparse = True, n_labels = 20,
return_indicator = 'sparse', allow_unlabeled = False)

# using binary relevance
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

# initialize binary relevance multi-label classifier
# with a gaussian naive bayes base classifier
classifier = BinaryRelevance(GaussianNB())

# train
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)
```

Comment: You didn't define X_train or y_train in your code

Comment: I believe you forgot to split the dataset into train and test

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to split the dataset into train and test sets.
 
Import the library

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Add this line before classifier.fit()

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Comment: I tried the way you suggested and it worked for me.your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it helped you?@abbaskhan

Answer (score 0):

X_train does not exist, you have to split between train and test :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
s =StandardScaler()
X_train = s.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = s.fit_transform(X_test)
```